# Missing Countries & locations from CultureInfo when trying to

Tags: .net, localization, globalization, cultureinfo

I need to localize an application and have noticed that several countries don't appear in the list of county codes associated to cultureInfo.

One example is Cyprus, I assume there might be others.

If i need to localize settings for Cyprus (or other missing ones) how would I rename my resource files that they would render the correct text and such?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When localizing to [Cyprus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus), you would need to either localize to Greek (for the Greek part of the island), or to Turkish (for the Turkish part). As the island is composed of these two cultures, it does not have a `CultureInfo` of its own.

Comment: Can you give me the example of the file name i should you for the resource file?

Comment: @Ian - it is `el` for Greek and `tr` for Turkish. You could also use `el-GR` for Greece, or `tr-TR` for Turkey. See this list: http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/globalization/demos/CultureInfo.aspx