# tilde `~` use in Enum

Tags: c#, enums

Iv'e look through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387424/what-is-the-tilde-in-the-enum-definition).

Can not seem to understand this line of code:

I'm trying to get as many cultures as i can.

```
CultureInfo[] cinfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);

public enum CultureTypes
{
    NeutralCultures = 1,
    SpecificCultures = 2,
    InstalledWin32Cultures = 4,
    AllCultures = 7,
    UserCustomCulture = 8,
    ReplacementCultures = 16,
    [Obsolete("This value has been deprecated.  Please use other values in CultureTypes.")]
    WindowsOnlyCultures = 32,
    [Obsolete("This value has been deprecated.  Please use other values in CultureTypes.")]
    FrameworkCultures = 64,
}
```

does the tilde makes the constructor behave like this?:

```
CultureInfo[] cinfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures | 
CultureTypes.NeutralCultures | 
CultureTypes.SpecificCultures | 
CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures | 
CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture | 
CultureTypes.ReplacementCultures );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression:

```
CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures
```

Is the equivalent (in natural language) of: "AllCultures except for NeutralCultures".

The bitwise complement operator `~` will negate the value of `CultureTypes.NeutralCultures`.

Let's do some bitwise math manually:

```
AllCultures            = 0111 // 1+2+4=7
NeutralCultures        = 0001 // 1
SpecificCultures       = 0010 // 2
InstalledWin32Cultures = 0100 // 4
```

So:

```
~NeutralCultures = 1110 // bits flipped
```

And:

```
AllCultures & ~NeutralCultures = 0111 & 1110
```

Which results in:

```
0111
1110
----
0110
```

`0110` is 6 in decimal, which is equivalent to `SpecificCultures | InstalledWin32Cultures`

Comment: Now I understand it. Basically it means give me all the options except one.

Answer (score 2):

~ is the Bitwise complement operator as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-complement-operator

Please see Luceros' comment under Odeds answer to this question: [Why not all countries are presented in CultureInfo.GetCultures()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139456/why-not-all-countries-are-presented-in-cultureinfo-getcultures), which explains that the Bitwise complement operator is used to state that Neutral Cultures should not be used in the result of the expression.

Comment: tnx, iv'e already knew about the Bitwise behavior, but still cant seem to figure out my line of code?