# ISO Lists different countries in environments

Tags: c#, iso

I have an usual problem where my country lists are different for each of the environments I have.

My test environment is missing Cameroon and Hong Kong is Hong Kong SAR.

I'm using the following code to retrieve my countries:

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

        foreach (var regionInfo in cultureInfo.Select(info => new RegionInfo(info.LCID)).Where(regionInfo => !cultureList.Contains(regionInfo.EnglishName)))
        {
                cultureList.Add(regionInfo.EnglishName);
        }
```

Any ideas what could be causing the discrepancies?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might want to read this answer [Why not all countries are presented in CultureInfo.GetCultures()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139456/why-not-all-countries-are-presented-in-cultureinfo-getcultures).

Essentially it comes down to where the environments are located.

Comment: Thanks for this, is there anyway to check what the culture is on a particular machine?

Comment: Best way I can think of would be to run it in code and log the result somewhere, can do it using CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;