# How to Find the Different .net version being referenced?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, regioninfo

I am trying to find the `ThreeLetterISORegionName` of country "Cyprus" and "Virgin Islands". hence so I have used `RegionInfo` class using `System.Globalization` from  `mscorlib` assembly.

```
RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo("CY");
Console.WriteLine(regionInfo.ThreeLetterISORegionName);
```

The above code works fine in my local machine. however after deploying to production I am getting `System.ArgumentException` with message

> The region name CY should not correspond to neutral culture; a specific culture name is required

In my local machine and server I am using `.net 4.5.2` version. 
`mscorlibv` assembly version is  `4.0.30319`

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: sounds like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920274/missing-countries-locations-from-cultureinfo-when-trying-to

Comment: Are you deploying to Azure? Not all cultures are supported on Azure App Services. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/963f02d1-bf04-430a-ab51-9c3fc0462e63/cultures-not-supported-on-azure-webapps?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: @RuiJarimba : Nope not azure.

Answer (score 1):

Later I found the root cause of this problem.

My local machine is Windows 10 which has the updated region info.

where my server OS is `windows server 2008` which doesnt have region
information on cyprus or Virgin Islands